# Mock Date object using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit3

A method of `MyService` class returns `java.util.Date` object and `MyManager` class is calling that method of `MyService` class. I am writing the test case for `MyManager` class.
when I mock

```
Mockito.when(manager.getDate())).thenReturn((Date)Mockito.any())
```

is not working. Could some one help me on this please?

Comment: I am using java4 and junit3

Comment: what do you mean by not working? compilation error, test case failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are using the syntax correctly. The `any` idiom is used for matching arguments when a method is called, not for specifying the return value of a mocked called. See [Matchers](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html) for details on how these work.

Try providing a real date as your return value.

I gather from your line of code that you might be using Mockito incorrectly. If you are testing `Manager` using a mocked `Service` then your code should likely look something like:

```
Date testDate = new Date("01/01/1970");
Service mockedService = mock(Service.class);
when(service.getDate()).thenReturn(testDate);
testManager.setService(service);
assertEquals(testDate, testManager.getServicesDate());
```

In other words, you wouldn't normally be mocking a `Manager` object (as implied by your code) if you are testing the `Manager` class.

Answer (score 1):

1. `any` is a Mockito matcher and usually used to match called function arguments and not for returning values. In most of situations, return value is concrete object and type is known so using `any()` in `thenReturn()` doesn't make sense.
2. Mockito mocking can be applied to methods of only mocked objects so if you are testing `MyManager` class which has a dependency on `MyService` class and if some of methods of `MyService` are intended to be mocked , you first need to create a mocked object for 'MyService' class and then use `when` clause to mock that method. `MyManager` will not be mocked.
3. Matchers like `any()` come into picture at point # 2, to match function argument types. In your case , its a *no parameter* function so no matchers needed.
4. If you wish to return a dummy  value then return that value via `thenReturn()` clause. You can return either `null` value or non - null value. Obviously, you will have to create objects if planning to return non - null value ( in your case , it might be a concrete `Date` object )

So your code should look like,

```
Mockito.when(service.getDate())).thenReturn(date);
```

OR `Mockito.when(service.getDate())).thenReturn(null);`

where `service` is a mocked object of `MyService` type and `date` is a pre created `Date` type object.

**We mock dependencies and not subjects under test.**